# DigitalOcean load balancer can't connect to my droplets

Tags: docker, deployment, load-balancing, digital-ocean

I've setup a load balancer to direct traffic to two droplets each having a container running an API service on port 8080. How do I set up my load balancer to connect to these two containers? I'm getting a 503 error whenever I try to access the API through the load balancer. However, I can access the API individually through the IP addresses of the droplet. How do I access it through the load balancer?

Pinging the IP address of the load balancer also works.

Here are my load balancer settings:

```
 - Forwarding rules
    1. HTTP on Port 80 -> Port 8080
    2. HTTP on port 8080 -> port 8080
 - Healthcheck on: http://0.0.0.0:80/
 - Sticky sessions: off 
 - SSL: No redirect
 - Proxty protocol: Disabled
 - Backend keepalive: yes
 - HTTP Idle Timeout: 90
```

It's pretty much the same as the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just had to changed the healthcheck port to the port the services are running on in the individual droplets (in this case 8080)

Comment: Hi did you have ngnix setup ? Because I'm facing the same issue now .

Answer (score 0):

Check the firewall settings on your droplets. Ensure that the firewall allows incoming traffic on port 8080 for the load balancer's IP address or the appropriate range if using a cloud provider load balancer.